# i call delete, but my d-tor isn't called, why?

Tags: c++

I wrote this piece of code ( I know it's an awful design but this is just a simplified simulation for real objects in the code that i'm working with, trying to inspect some memory related bug), when running it with debugger, i can reach the "delete" in the Holder d-tor, but the d-tor of TrueObject is never called. why is that? (compiled with vs2017)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ComonBaseA {
public:
    ComonBaseA() { cout << "ComonBaseA" << endl; }
    virtual ~ComonBaseA() { cout << "~ComonBaseA"<<endl; }
};

class Proxy : public ComonBaseA {
public:
    Proxy() { cout << "Proxy" << endl; }
    void invoke();
    ~Proxy();
private:
    ComonBaseA* imp = nullptr;

};

class A : public Proxy {
public:
    A() { cout << "A with invoke" << endl; invoke();}
    A(bool bNoProxy) { cout << "A (empty)" << endl; }
    virtual ~A() { cout << "~A"<<endl; }
};

class TrueObject;

class Holder {
public:
    Holder() { cout << "Holder" << endl; }
    void hold(TrueObject* t) {
        cout << "holding" << endl;
        _t = t;
    }
    ~Holder() {
        cout << "~Holder" << endl;
        delete _t;

    }

private:
    TrueObject* _t = nullptr;
};

class TrueObject {
public:
    TrueObject(Holder* h) { 
        cout << "TrueObject" << endl;
        h->hold(this);
    }
    ~TrueObject() { 
        cout << "~TrueObject"<<endl; 
    }
};



class AImp : public A, public Holder {
public:
    AImp() : A(true), Holder() {
        cout << "AImp" << endl;
        _t = new TrueObject(this);
    }
    ~AImp() { cout << "~AImp"<<endl; }

private:
    TrueObject* _t = nullptr;
};


void Proxy::invoke() {
    imp = new AImp();
}

Proxy::~Proxy() {
    cout << "~Proxy"<<endl;
    delete imp;
}


int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ComonBaseA
Proxy
A with invoke
ComonBaseA
Proxy
A (empty)
Holder
AImp
TrueObject
holding
~A
~Proxy
~AImp
~Holder
~A
~Proxy
~ComonBaseA
~ComonBaseA
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for me to read. Could you experiment and cut out pieces of code until you get the minimum that still has the problem? You might find that will show you the solution!

Comment: When I compile your code clang [complains that the dtor of Holder tries to delete an incomplete type (TrueObject)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8815945f35738eaf). Have you tried moving the definition of Holder's dtor after you have a full declaration of TrueObject (and not just the forward decl)?

Comment: @Borgleader, thank you. it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile your code clang complains that the dtor of Holder tries to delete an >incomplete type (TrueObject). Have you tried moving the definition of Holder's dtor after >you have a full declaration of TrueObject (and not just the forward decl)?

fixing it solved the problem. thanks!